# Any English equivalent for Russian idiom "to write for the desk drawer"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

It means "to write literary works, knowing that they will not pass censorship and be published". I am looking for some English equivalents that can be used to describe not only writing but also doing different things like taking photos for example for oneself and refusing to publish them. Thank you very much in advance

---

Let's just find an equivalent for "doing things for yourself and not caring whether it will be published or not". A good example is Kafka most of whose books were published after his death

Comment: Taking photos for yourself and **not** refusing to publish them? Do you mean either refusing to publish them or not intending to publish them? Not refusing to publish them would seem a little at odds with the general gist of the question…

Comment: Well historically, English speaking nations have edged towards liberal democracy, so book censorship is less of a common occurrence